# AxiosError: Network Error --- ReactNative with Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, expo

I'm developping an expo go application with axios and i'm trying to connect to an api that i'm currently building but i'm getting this [AxiorError: Network Error].
I'm new in React Native development but i already work with mobile development, my url is valid ( i also tested using the browser of the emulator so it is hitting the api by the emulator network and getting the proper results)

I'm using android

This is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.xxx.x.x:81/api'
});

export default api;
```

than i have this method:

```
import api from "./Api";
    
export async function searchMenu() {
    
    const response = await api.get('/menu');                

    return response.data;
    
}
```

and i call it in

```
import { searchMenu } from "@/services/MenuApi"

export default function Home(){   
console.log(searchMenu())
  }
```

EDIT:
This is the result when i call:

searchMenu().then(console.log).catch((err) => console.log(err.response?.data, err.toJSON()))

```
LOG  undefined {"code": "ERR_NETWORK", "columnNumber": undefined, "config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "baseURL": "http://192.168.0.3:81/api", "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "/menu", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "description": undefined, "fileName": undefined, "lineNumber": undefined, "message": "Network Error", "name": "AxiosError", "number": undefined, "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error
```

Comment: First, you need to await the result of your async function, eg `searchMenu().then(console.log)`. Second, you could do with some error logging... `searchMenu().then(console.log).catch((err) => console.error(err.response?.data, err.toJSON()))`

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but i'm still getting the error, I will put the json in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out, the problem was in my API:

If anyone is using an ASP.NET API with .net6+ and having this problem, in your Program.cs file comment the line:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

I still dont know why the url worked in the emulator browser but no in the emulator app, but now is working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to make changes in your Android manifest file to support HTTP requests, by default Android supports only HTTPS requests and I can see your `baseUrl` is based on HTTP only.

Try putting usesCleartextTraffic in your application tag

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
/>
```

You can also try APIs with HTTPS if you have one, It will run without any changes `https://192.xxx.x.x:81/api`

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, I already thought on the usesCleartextTraffic and that helped me in another applications with Xamarin and Maui but i'm really new in React Native and using Expo Go....
I really did not want to eject my expo project to get acess to the manifest, do you know any way to change it without doing this?

Comment: I checked into their [app.config doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#properties), they haven't mentioned anything as such.

one option is to use your own development expo version, you will not be ejected from expo. you can dig more about [expo prebuilt feature](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/). When you create build, expo will add all the configs to Android Manifest file at the time of pre-building and you can use the expo in the way you like.